# Signed jar throwing permission exceptions with appletviewer

Tags: java, applet, jar-signing, signed-applet, appletviewer

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue with signed jars not working under appletviewer. My main goal is to run it outside of the browser, so I tried using appletviewer - if you have other suggestions, let me know.

Here's the context:

- Ubuntu 11.10
- Java:

  ```
  $ java -version
  java version "1.6.0_26"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
  ```

Here's the problem:

- I have a jar myjar.jar that contains an applet inside
- It works properly in browser, but not when run under appletviewer
- The jar is signed:

  ```
  $ jarsigner -verify -certs -verbose -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts myjar.jar
  ...
  smk     <file size> <file date> <file name>

        X.509, CN=xxx, OU=xxx, OU=xxx, O=xxx, L=xxx, ST=xxx, C=xxx
        [certificate is valid from m/d/y h:m PM to m/d/y h:m PM]
        X.509, CN=yyy, OU=yyy, OU=yyy, O=yyy, C=yyy
        [certificate is valid from m/d/y h:m PM to m/d/y h:m PM]
        [KeyUsage extension does not support code signing]
        X.509, OU=zzz, O=zzz, C=zzz (alias1)
        [certificate is valid from m/d/y h:m PM to m/d/y h:m PM]
  ...
  jar verified.
  ```

and, though the intermediate signing certificate (yyy above) is not present, the root one (zzz - or alias1) is:

```
$ keytool -list -v -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts -storepass changeit|grep alias1
alias1, Mmm d, yyyy, trustedCertEntry,
```

Running this:

```
$ appletviewer myhtml.html
```

gives:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission preferences)
```

Question set 1:

- Is the assumption that when a root certificate is present, all following intermediate certificates are assumed acceptable for verification purposes? In above case, is it necessary to have yyy in the cacerts file?
- When jar is signed, as myjar.jar is, is it assumed that appletviewer should run with no restrictions?
- Is there a better way to run it to avoid this?
- Why is this working differently in browser than with appletviewer?

Not being sure of above, I tried adding the certificate to another local file, called cacerts2. I can confirm that:

- keytool lists that certificate in cacerts
- jarsigner output is now like this:

  ```
  $ jarsigner -verify -certs -verbose -keystore cacerts2 myjar.jar
  ...
  smk     <file size> <file date> <file name>

        X.509, CN=xxx, OU=xxx, OU=xxx, O=xxx, L=xxx, ST=xxx, C=xxx
        [certificate is valid from m/d/y h:m PM to m/d/y h:m PM]
        X.509, CN=yyy, OU=yyy, OU=yyy, O=yyy, C=yyy (alias2)
        [certificate is valid from m/d/y h:m PM to m/d/y h:m PM]
        [KeyUsage extension does not support code signing]
        X.509, OU=zzz, O=zzz, C=zzz (alias1)
        [certificate is valid from m/d/y h:m PM to m/d/y h:m PM]
  ...
  jar verified.
  ```

Note that now I have the intermediate alias (yyy - or alias2) present in the output and verified both against alias1 and alias2. Running the appletviewer like this:

```
$ appletviewer -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts2 -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit myhtml.html
```

still results in the same exception.

Question set 2:

- Is the above the right way to supply the trust store?
- Does the above mean that appletviewer will use it in the same way as jarsigner will when passed -keystore command for its verification purposes?

The third thing I tried is making a policy file like this (this is in mypolicy.policy):

```
keystore "cacerts2";
// Tried with this and without the next line:
//keystorePasswordURL "cacerts.pass";
// where file cacerts.pass has only "changeit" / "changeit\n" in it (tried both)

// Tried the following three:
grant signedBy "alias1" {
//grant signedBy "alias2" {
//grant {
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "preferences";
};
```

and running like this:

```
$ appletviewer -J-Djava.security.policy=mypolicy.policy myhtml.html
```

and like this:

```
$ appletviewer -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts2 -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -J-Djava.security.policy=mypolicy.policy myhtml.html
```

Results:

- grant without any signedBy specs worked, so I can confirm the policy is picked up
- grant with either signedBy is failing

Question set 3:

- Is this the correct way to specify policy and signedBy? I find the docs from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) incomplete on this topic
- Is policy file even used when jar is signed?
- Any other ideas? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My main goal is to run it outside of the browser,..

Use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), which could launch applets free-floating since around the 1.2 days.  (Or convert the code to a frame.)

If the main point of this is testing, you might try [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/).  AFAIR I never got around to implementing a sand-box for it (so even unsigned applet code would behave as if it were trusted).

---

AppletViewer *used* to launch applets without a security sand-box, even if they were not signed. Now it is the opposite and has a sand-box, and there is no way to get it to accept signed code as trusted!

IDEs seem to apply a policy file to the viewer, to get it to act however the user configures the IDE.

Comment: Touché! :) From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jws/developersguide/syntax.html#security): Each application is, by default, run in a restricted execution environment, similar to the Applet sandbox. ... If an application requests full access, then all JAR files must be signed. Thanks Andrew!

Comment: Just wanted to say that's exactly what I need - a sandboxed-by-default environment (and it will ask you to confirm new certificates) that will work only with signed files unless explicitly overridden in jnlp. I was aware of JWS, just never crossed my mind (doh!) to use them in this particular case...

Comment: Cool.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Comment: (Point of pedantry: JaWS wasn't in 1.2. It started out as a separate product. Indeed I remember sometime after 1.2 was released using JaWS 0.4.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline  I wrote in the info. page on JWS (linked above) *"JWS was first offered as a separate download **with the release of Java 1.2,** and could launch both applications and applets as free floating entities. The functionality became co-bundled with J2SE 1.4.2. Since 1.6.0_10 (the Next Generation Java Plug-In), JWS can also be used to configure applets that remain embedded in a web page."*  Are you saying that **bold** part should read more like *"prior to the release of 1.3"*?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I've also made an edit to the answer to make the start time of JWS less specific.  (Though I don't think it is very relevant to this question, so it might be best just to delete that part.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson That wiki talking about Java Web Services? Fixed it. (Just pedantry. Did +1.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Thanks for adding the specific date.  :)